# In ASP.NET MVC 2 asynchronous controllers, do Action Filters execute asynchronously?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, asynchronous

In ASP.NET MVC 2 asynchronous controllers, we can do something like this:

```
public class SomeController : AsyncController
{
    [Blurb]
    public void FooAsync()
    {
        this.AsyncManager.OutstandingOperations.Increment();

        Task.Factory.StartNew(
            () =>
            {
                this.AsyncManager.Parameters["result"] = new BazResult();
                this.AsyncManager.OutstandingOperations.Decrement();
            });
    }

    public ActionResult FooCompleted(ActionResult result)
    {
        return result;
    }
}
```

My question is, does the action filter **"Blurb"** in this case execute asynchronously? In other words, is its synchronous nature automatically wrapped into an asynchronous call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took a look under the covers at **AsyncControllerActionInvoker** and it looks like it does indeed wrap them into a set of asynchronous calls and continuations. It makes a call to **BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters** which in turn sets up **InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronously**.

For those who are curious, the source is on codeplex.

Comment: So the filter is executed on yet another thread?  Doesn't BeginInvoke use a threadpool thread?  Doesn't that defeat the purpose of an async call?

Comment: My understanding is that the asynchronous calls do not use the same thread pool that web requests use, so IIS doesn't face thread starvation.